# Using Beautifulsoup To Scrape the data from a worldmap and store this into a csv-file

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

try to scrape the data of the site https://www.startupblink.com/startups - in order to grab all the startups: well i think this is a good chance to do this with python and beautiful soup.

**Technically**, we could use Python and Beautiful Soup to scrape the data from the website https://www.startupblink.com/startups

**what is needed:**  .. here some overfiew on the steps:

first we need to send a GET request to the website using the requests library in Python.
then we parse the HTML content of the response using Beautiful Soup.

we need to find the HTML elements that contain the startup data we re interested in using Beautiful Soup's find or find_all methods.

afterwards we try to extract the relevant information from the HTML elements using Beautiful Soup's string or get methods.
finally we store the data in a format of our choice, such as a CSV file or a database ( note - if we would use pandas it would be a bit easier i get )

Here's some first ideas to get this  started:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Send an HTTP request to the website's URL and retrieve the HTML content
url = 'https://www.startupblink.com/startups'
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all the startup listings on the page
startup_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'startup-list-item'})

# Create a CSV file to store the extracted data
with open('startup_data.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Description', 'Location', 'Website'])

    # Loop through each startup listing and extract the relevant information
    for startup in startup_listings:
        name = startup.find('a', {'class': 'startup-link'}).text.strip()
        description = startup.find('div', {'class': 'startup-description'}).text.strip()
        location = startup.find('div', {'class': 'startup-location'}).text.strip()
        website = startup.find('a', {'class': 'startup-link'})['href']

        # Write the extracted data to the CSV file
        writer.writerow([name, description, location, website])
```

at this point i think that i have to rework the code - i getback only a tiny csv file with 35 bytes.

i will have to run more tests - to makesure that i get the right  approach

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using BeautifulSoup for dynamically delivered content, use the api endpoint from which the data originates. Iterate a series of pages and merge the data frames to finally convert them into any format:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 

pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            requests.get(f'https://www.startupblink.com/api/entities?entity=startups&page={page}&sortBy=rank&order=desc&leaderType=1').json()['page']
        )
        for page in range(0,5)
    ]
).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: hello dear HedgeHog, many thanks for the quick headsup.This is awesome and shows how powerful pandas were. This solution is so great - i am overwhelmed. i am trying to cathcup the idea how to fetch even more - did you narrow down the range of results  with the range  (0,5) - i will digg deeper into all that - and in the method you have choosen.  Meanwhile many many thanks.  You made my day ;)

Comment: Correct, to understand the example and to try it out, it should be enough to use only the first x pages, also in order not to load the page itself unnecessarily with queries. The number can be increased accordingly and in case of doubt a while loop can be used, but it should be sufficient for an adaptation.